# Is ROS-I support ABB S4C controller?

Tags: ros, microcontroller, abb, ros-industrial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I am new to ROS.And I have an IRB 1400 robot arm and S4C controller. For now, I can't find any evidence show that ABB package support S4C controller. Had anyone try this? Or it just can't work?

Here is the link of related answer: [is ROS industrial supported on ABB IRB 6400 m97a controller?](http://answers.ros.org/question/227741/is-ros-industrial-supported-on-abb-irb-6400-m97a-controller/)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234003/is-ros-i-support-abb-s4c-controller?/) by [ROS_HUA](https://answers.ros.org/users/26699/ros_hua/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-05-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mohitrochlani](https://answers.ros.org/users/120438/mohitrochlani/) on 2022-10-13**:
@ROS_HUA did you implemented the solution were you able to control the robot with ROS and s4c controller?? I am also looking for the same , @gvdhooom , how to interface your ROS PC with S4c controller and how to communicate with the ros moveit package that i have build , I am new to it , any help would be appreciated, I have done only simulation part , i want to implement it on the real bot i have ABB IRB 2400 with s4c plus controller? can you guys help me out

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-10-13**:
It's not a good idea to post comments on questions from 2016 with already accepted answers.

In any case: nothing has changed since I posted my original answer. Or at least: I'm not aware of anyone having ported `abb_driver` to S4C controllers or made anything else available.

That doesn't mean it doesn't exist. Just that I don't remember anyone releasing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd really recommend you send a message to the [ROS-Industrial mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/swri-ros-pkg-dev) and see whether someone has already done this. Most users of those packages will be on the mailing list, so you'll have a better chance of getting a good answer there.

Do please report back if/when you get an answer.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-05-10**:
You could always just try and see if you can get it to work, of course. The sources for `abb_driver` are [here](https://github.com/ros-industrial/abb/tree/indigo-devel/abb_driver).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I get some feeback and useful information about this topic in the [ROS-Industrial mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/swri-ros-pkg-dev).

Here is the link of the topic: [Is ROS-I support ABB S4C controller?](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/swri-ros-pkg-dev/liFni3wMTCU)
(shortly,it can work)

---

Originally posted by [ROS_HUA](https://answers.ros.org/users/26699/ros_hua/) with karma: 11 on 2016-05-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-05-13**:
Thanks for letting us know.